# Animation (Adobe After Effects): Text rotating around object with proper "3-dimensional" perspective

Tags: typography, animation, adobe-after-effects

This question is based on a previous inquiry into how to animate a rotating string of text, the original question can be found here: [Animation (Adobe After Effects): Text rotating without cylindric wrapping of text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87432/animation-adobe-after-effects-text-rotating-without-cylindric-wrapping-of-tex)

The final result of this research looks like this:

[image: Rotating Text]

As Cai (who answered my initial question) suggested, this is done by creating an oval-shaped masked for the text layer, turning off the `Perpendicular To Path` option under `Path Options` and using the `First/Last Margin` value to animate the rotation.

[image: Work-In-Progress-1]

Now, I would like to place another shape inside the rotating text, that is, let the text rotate around it. So far, I don't see any way to do so, as the shape can either sit on top or underneath the text layer. Is there any way (possibly by masking the text when it moves "behind" the shape which is supposed to like rotating around?) to create this animation properly in After Effects?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I normally just duplicate the thing you want in front and behind, literally place them in front and behind and mask each as necessary. An example...

Mask your shape...

[image]

Invert the mask (I've actually just dragged two anchors on the mask to the opposite end of the shape) on a duplicate layer...

[image]

Order your layers as needed...

[image]

Which gives us this:

[image]